# ssis ado.net destination has failed to acquire the connection

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I am Transferring data from sql server source db to sql server destination db (cross db).
but some times getting error "ssis ado.net destination has failed to acquire the connection.The connection may have been corrupted"

Comment: What does your connection string look like? What components are you using to transfer the data? Is there a particular reason you're using the ado.net connection managers?

Comment: No but we know both are sql server db(cross db).

Comment: with source we are using connection windows authentication but for destination we are using sql server authentication.

Answer (score -1):

1. configure your connection as xml
2. set variable in connection
3. set computer name & logic [Admin]